# Progresso da tag parece que está congelado

Tags: bug, status-pronto, medalhas

Não vi ninguém reclamar disso aqui. O problema basicamente é que o progresso da medalha da tag parece estar congelado:

<kbd>[image: Progresso para a medalha de tag]</kbd>

Me parece estar congelado em 469 há alguns dias, embora eu não tenha certeza disso. Isso contrasta com outra parte da minha página de usuário que diz que ao invés de 469x160 eu deveria ter 509x173:

<kbd>[image: Pontos da tag]</kbd>

Ao escolher o ícone para selecionar a próxima medalha, também é mostrado 509x173:

<kbd>[image: Progresso da medalha na seleção]</kbd>

Bônus: Observe que há uma linha cinza por cima da parte do texto, ficando mais ou menos como "medalh<strike>a da tag:</strike>". Esse bug já foi relatado e corrigido antes, mas voltou.

Vi essa pergunta referente a isso no metão: ["Next tag badge" panel score and answers counter discrepancy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267818/176034).

Editado: Um *workaround* para este bug é escolher uma tag diferente para acompanhar no painel "Selecione sua próxima medalha" e então abrir o painel de novo para escolher de volta a tag que você quer de fato acompanhar. Ao fazer isso, ele passou a aparecer 509x173 para mim.

Comment: Será que pode ser o cache do browser?

Comment: Aqui acontece exatamente a mesma coisa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já tem alguns meses que estes bugs não são mais reproduzíveis ([link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/280548/176034)), e portanto podem ser considerados como corrigidos.